# QSqlError("5", "Unable to fetch row", "database is locked")

Tags: qt, sqlite, qt5, qtsql

I am getting this error "`QSqlError("5", "Unable to fetch row", "database is locked")`"

I have done my research and I think the problem arises from the fact that I am executing an `INSERT` query while the `SELECT` query is still active, which locks the database. Now I'd imagine people run into this problem often since it is common to write to a database based on the output of a `SELECT` query, so I wanted to ask what is the best way to solve this? Would I be able to fetch the query (using `query.next()`) after closing it with `query.finish()` to unlock the database? Or should I store the result in a temporary container, close the query then iterate over the temporary container?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: The "database is locked" error happens only when there is *another* connection with an active transaction. But in any case, if you modify data that you are currently reading, the result is unspecified.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the result is unspecified"?

Comment: The results rows might be read directly from the table, or from a temporary sorted list, or from an index. So when you are making changes while iterating over a table, it is possible to get missing or duplicate entries.

Comment: I thought that by the time you are calling `query.next()` the query already has the results in a static form (it is not actively reading from the database every time I call `query.next()` right?)

Comment: SQLite computes result rows on demand, as far as possible.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a database reader on when you run this? I had a similar issue that only occurred when I had `DB Browser for SQLite` running. Make sure that you don't have any other software that has your database file open. I don't always have this issue with using `DB Browser for SQLite` but when I do, closing the program fixes it.

It addition, I tend to run `query.finish()` after each query is complete, to ensure no interaction.

I hope this helps you out!